# How to hide Permalink section from a Custom Post Type's post?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, posts

I want to hide the permalink section under the title of a post for a particular post type in Wordpress. How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Under `register_post_types` add the following arguments:

```
'public' => false,  // it's not public, it shouldn't have it's own permalink, and so on
'publicly_queryable' => true,  // you should be able to query it
'show_ui' => true,  // you should be able to edit it in wp-admin
'exclude_from_search' => true,  // you should exclude it from search results
'show_in_nav_menus' => false,  // you shouldn't be able to add it to menus
'has_archive' => false,  // it shouldn't have archive page
'rewrite' => false,  // it shouldn't have rewrite rules
```

What you need is the first element `'public' => false`.

Comment: In some case we need to keep custom post type public as true

Comment: I agree, but according to the question, this is the right way to actually hide the permalink. It really depends on what and how you want to implement in WP

Comment: Original answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108658/62753

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by adding the value 'permalink' to the 'hide_on_screen' array of ACF (Advanced Custom Fields). Or doing this via the ACF Field group configurator.

```
        'hide_on_screen' => array(
        0 => 'the_content',
        1 => 'excerpt',
        2 => 'custom_fields',
        3 => 'discussion',
        4 => 'comments',
        5 => 'revisions',
        6 => 'slug',
        7 => 'author',
        8 => 'format',
        9 => 'categories',
        10 => 'tags',
        11 => 'send-trackbacks',
        12 => 'permalink',
    ),
```